# Probability and profits from sharing the earnings of a lottery

Tags: probability

Recently (new year's eve) I was in the annual convention meeting of the company I am currently working. A lottery took place where 140 people participated for 5 prices of `$100` each.

I haven't got serious education in mathematics (even If I am a developer, CS graduate..) so I got the feeling that If a group of people (my 3 close colleagues in the company plus me) agrees to share the earnings of whatever is won, there will be a lot more probabilities to win. Considering that winning `$25` seems more fun than `$0` and risking to lose `$100`.

I tried to convert this idea to maths.

- For the first lottery price, our probabilities of winning are 4/140 -> `$25`, more than 1/140 => `$100`.
- For the second lottery price, If the first is won, we have (4-1)/(140-1) probabilities to win another `$25`, making it `$50`, or losing `$100` in again 1/140, or winning nothing (considering that we failed in the first one).

The thing goes on like this but I feel like I am lost somewhere. What is the probability of winning after the whole lottery? Is 1/140 + 1/139 + 1/138 + 1/137 worth it of winning `$100` than it is to win 4/140 + 4/139 or 3/139 + 4/138 or 3/138 or 2/138 etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear where there were four of you or five (four colleagues plus you) or whether a ticket could win more than one prize.

Assuming that there were four of you, and that no ticket could win more than one prize, the probability of at least one prize is $1$ minus the probability of no prizes, which is $$1-\dfrac{136}{140}\times\dfrac{135}{139}\times\dfrac{134}{138}\times\dfrac{133}{137}\times\dfrac{132}{136} \approx 0.13678$$ which is less than four times the probability of winning on your own of $\frac{5}{140} \approx 0.03571$, though offset by the possibility your little group might win more than one prize.

Comment: It's 3 plus me = 4, I edited my question, thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit why you solved it like this? Why 1 minus 136/140 and why did you divided with 140 (and also the rest of them). Is this some kind of factorial ?

Comment: The probability the first prize does not go to your group is the probability it goes to somebody else which is $\frac{136}{140}$.  Given that has happened, the probability the second  prize does not go to your group is the probability it goes to somebody else which is $\frac{135}{139}$, and so on.

Comment: And what If for example someone else wins the second price? I understand that the probabilities of the third would be 133/138. Is there a way other than manually to calculate all the probabilities? If I understand well, the solution you provide shows what is the probability of winning one price, If in every turn someone else wins it. What If two of my group win the first and the third prize? Do I need an array to calculate all of these ?

Comment: $0.13678$ is the probability that your group wins at least one prize.  My calculations look at the probability of not winning any prize to avoid the complications you point out.